# My Emoji Soft Keyboard is not supporting EditText Field in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, emoji

I want to display emoji in my soft keyboard. but i don't have any EditText.

 I use this code:

```
<key android:codes="111222" android:keyIcon="@drawable/smiley"/>
```

and then onkey() method in softkeyboard implement like this:

```
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes){

----
----   

else if(primaryCode == 111222){
    int codeOfEmoji= 0x1F60A;
            int unicode = 0x1F349;
            String text = String.valueOf(Character.toChars(unicode));
            ic.commitText(text, 1);
    }
----
----
}
```

Now, I have a problem. I need to press delete key twice to delete this emoji.
This is my delete code:

```
   @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();

        switch(primaryCode){

        case android.inputmethodservice.Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
        ic.commitText("", 1);
        ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
        break;
}
```

How to solve it? Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough credit to comment but does it showing now the emoji?
You can try and translate the input first to unicode and then display using this: http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F300.pdf